# Ошибка при insert'e в БД hql hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Подскажите как сделать что бы `id` генерировался автоматически

> **Ошибка:**
> Identifier generator reported it does not support implicit id handling
> as part of bulk insertions [insert into EmailEntity
> (toUserId,fromUserId,subject,messages,dateTime,statusInbox,statusSend)
> select
> :toUserId,:fromUserId,:subject,:messages,:dateTime,:statusInbox,:statusSend
> from ispeakschool.crm.dao.entity.EmailEntity ee]

```
    var session = getSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.createQuery("insert into EmailEntity (toUserId,fromUserId,subject,messages,dateTime,statusInbox,statusSend) select :toUserId,:fromUserId,:subject,:messages,:dateTime,:statusInbox,:statusSend from EmailEntity ee")
            .setParameter("toUserId", userIdTo)
            .setParameter("fromUserId", userIdFrom)
            .setParameter("subject", subject)
            .setParameter("messages", message)
            .setParameter("dateTime", new Date())
            .setParameter("statusInbox", EmailStatus.NEW)
            .setParameter("statusSend", EmailStatus.SEND)
            .executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

**`EmailEntity`:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Comment: если не ошибаюсь `hql` не поддерживает вставку как указано в вопросе. А чем Вам не нравится вариант `session.save(new EmailEntity (toUserId ,fromUserId, subject, messages, new Date(), EmailStatus.NEW, EmailStatus.SEND));` ?

Comment: @MrFylypenko теперь появилась ошибка
`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: эта ошибка говорит, что пытаетесь сохранить сущность, у которой id 4, и с таким ИД строка в БД уже существует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался всем спасибо за помощь

> **Вот решение:**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вы не можете выполнять запросы на добавление сущьностей без указания `id`, данная часть не работает в произвольном запросе. Вот примеры стратегий использования аннотации для генерации ключей [`@GeneratedValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html):

Example 1:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="CUST_SEQ")
 @Column(name="CUST_ID")
 public Long getId() { return id; }
```

Example 2:

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=TABLE, generator="CUST_GEN")
 @Column(name="CUST_ID")
 Long id;
```

Comment: при старте выдается ошибка
`Unknown Id.generator: CUST_GEN `

Comment: Не понял, в чем ошибка?

Comment: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: CUST_GEN`

Comment: У вас нет такого генератора, и в вопросе у вас нет такого исключения.