# Запись в БД прошла успешно. Захожу, а там пусто(

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть простенький контроллер

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/crm/incoming_request")

public class IncomingRequestController {

    @Autowired

    IncomingRequestRepo incomingRequestRepo;


    @RequestMapping("/add")
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addIncomingRequest (@RequestBody IncomingRequest incomingRequest){

         incomingRequest.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.now());
         IncomingRequest savedIncomingRequest = incomingRequestRepo.save(incomingRequest);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedIncomingRequest);
    }
}
```

Он из приходящего JSON записывает сущность в базу.

Hibernate пишет что запись прошла успешно

```
Hibernate: insert into incoming_request (internal_click_id, client_id, date_time, event_source_url, fbc, fbclid, fbp, glickid, glickid_first_visit_date, page_title, rb_clickid, type_incoming_request_id, user_agent, utm_campaign, utm_campaign_id, utm_content, utm_content_id, utm_medium, utm_source, utm_term, utm_term_id, yclid, yclid_first_visit_date, ymclid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Postman тоже, что всё хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Захожу в Базу, там - пусто. Обновляю - пусто((( Я не могу понять, почему?

Comment: Может не в ту базу смотрите? Какая база и как прописана в конфиге?

Comment: Точно ту, так как у меня всего одна база на локалке. егодня созданная

Comment: В теории вы можете в приложении использовать БД в оперативнее, h2, например, а не ту что у вас локально. Ну или вы что то не то с id сделали. Покажите репозиторий и модель данных для бд

Comment: У меня не в репозитории, на локалке всё. Вроде, всё перепроверил. Вот https://s.mail.ru/Tjtv/hHkyKfLVt

Comment: Я про репозиторий IncomingRequestRepo) Что по ссылке - смотреть не стану - не хожу по незнакомым ссылкам. Добавьте лучше прямо в тело вопроса (если картинка) или дайте ссылку на что-то другое (GitHub, если там код)

Comment: Если запись сохранилась в базе данных, то она будет видна а случае если транзакция завершена успешно. То что hibernate пишет, ни о чем не говорит. Без знания причины, почему данные не вставляются в базу данных, невозможно делать какое либо предположение. Вот например одна из причин и ее решение, находится [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828799/204920).